# MS SQL 2017: Generate estimate execution plan take more than 3 min

Tags: execution-plan, sql-server-2017, columnstore

Sometimes generate Execution Plan (estimated) for simple query take `~3min`

Query:

```
SELECT MAX(field) FROM table_name
WHERE  Org = x and PartKey = y
```

The table is columnstore cluster index

`SQL Server 2017 Standard edition`

[Estimated plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyvAXHY8E)

Thank you

Comment: Do you see any blocking during the plan generation?

Comment: @DanGuzman, I did not saw any blocking

Comment: Where were you looking for blocking? I didn't see any bears today but I wasn't at a zoo. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand my question is quite different. I want see your bear but don't know where is zoo. During the plan generation I checked couple of time sp_whoisactive and now process was blocked it. So my question is how i get to zoo where should I look for problem.